# COMO ACTUALIZO TABLA PRODUCTOS CON DATOS DESDE POO

Tags: php, poo, update, actualizacion

Buenas tardes necesito actualizar mi tabla factura_producto cuando se elimina  una orden estas son mis tablas:

[image: Tablas de mi base de datos]

este es mi codigo

esta es mi funcion q no me corre es decir no me actualiza el stock en mi tabla factura_producto:

```
    public function actualizar($invoiceId)
        {
            $sqlupdateItemca = "
            update factura_producto join facturacopia
            on factura_producto.productCode=facturacopia.item_code
            set factura_producto.quantityInStock = 
 facturacopia.order_item_quantity+factura_producto.quantityInStock 
                wher facturacopia.order_id = '" . $invoiceId. "'  ";
            mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlupdateItemca);
            
        }
```

y quiero q corra aqui:

```
public function deleteInvoice($invoiceId)
{
    $sqlQuery = "
        DELETE FROM " . $this->invoiceOrderTable . " 
        WHERE order_id = '" . $invoiceId . "'";
    mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
    $this->deleteInvoiceItems($invoiceId);
    return 1;
    $this->actualizar($invoiceId);
```

Comment: Tienes mal escrito el **WHER** aquí: ```wher facturacopia.order_id = '" . $invoiceId. "' ``` cámbialo por ```WHERE``` y ya nos comentas.

Comment: Deberías resolver esto a nivel de base de datos, mediante disparadores (TRIGGER) y/o definiendo reglas de *integridad referencial*, así, evitarás tener que encargar a un extraño (PHP) algo que el propio dueño (base de datos) sabe hacer mejor, evitando posibles errores y ganando en rapidez.